# Android camera2 CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF and CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to set exact `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`, but still have `CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` focus. According to Android documentation, to set `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` I need set `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF`. But in this mode, I can't set `CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`, because it works only if `CONTROL_AE_MODE != OFF`. So, looks like it's impossible. But Camera FV-5 have `CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` focus and manual set `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME`.
How is it possible? My device is Nexus5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed set `CONTROL_MODE` to `AUTO` (and `CONTROL_AF_MODE` to whatever you want) yet still set `CONTROL_AE_MODE` to `OFF`.

I know the documentation doesn't read like it allows this, but I do it all the time to successfully separate control of the two on my Nexus 5. The `CONTROL_MODE` seems to only *enforce* overall control when set to `OFF`, but merely "suggests" it when set to `AUTO`. That is, you can override each of AF/AE/AWB using their `*_CONTROL_MODE` settings in the latter case, but not the former.

Comment: I tried CONTROL_MODE_AUTO and AE_MODE_OFF, but it doesn't work. Sometimes focus works fine, but sometimes it broken. Also this issue happens in Camera FV-5 sometimes. So, looks like focus behavior really depends on device if CONTROL_AE_MODE is OFF.

Comment: In CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE the device can initiate its own focus search- it may happen to do so and then the frame you capture is in the middle of the search and thus is not in focus. Is this possibly the case you are referring to? Have you checked the AF_STATE of those frames which it is not working for?

Comment: Focus is not searching and AF_STATE is INACTIVE.

Comment: i am trying `CONTROL_AE_MODE` to `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH` but aut flash is not working for video recording. any solution.. pls help